# Python - if dictionary key is in line print value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, replace

I am trying to check if in the lines of one file of mine there are the keys of a dictionary, and if that's the case I want to replace them with their respecting value.
Here is my code:

```
import sys
file1 = sys.argv[1]
dictionary = {key1 : value1 , key2 : value2 , ecc...}

with open (file) as f:
    for line in f:
        if any(e in line for e in dictionary.keys()):
            print(line.replace(e,dictionary[e]))
```

Comment: Please provide an example of what a couple of lines could look like in your file

Comment: What's the input? What's the actual output? What's the desired output?

Comment: Are you trying to check if an entire line is the dictionary key, or is the line of form "foo bar ... key1 ..." and you're trying to match each space-separated word?

Comment: What is `e`? The first key that matches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you're trying to do is something like this:

```
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        for k,v in dictionary.items():
            line = line.replace(k, v)
        print(line)
```

That is, for each key/value in the dictionary, replace in the line occurrences of that key with the associated value.

Alternatively, you could read the whole file in one go and just run the replacements on the whole thing:

```
with open(file) as f:
    data = f.read()
for k,v in dictionary.items():
    data = data.replace(k, v)
print(data)
```

And if you're in Python 2, you should use [`.iteritems()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) instead of [`.items()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items).

Comment: Thanks, your solution works very well, but is giving me some problems for the biggest datasets. Point in case: my dictionary has 13999 keys and my file has 840005 lines. Do you by any chance have some idea to make the script faster?

Comment: You could perform your replacements on the whole contents of the file in one go (see my edit). Other than that, I don't know.